# Does WSL2 cause the same performance issues as Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-10, performance, hyper-v, wsl2

WSL2 ["uses [the] Hyper-V architecture" through the "Virtual Machine Platform"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq#does-wsl-2-use-hyper-v-will-it-be-available-on-windows-10-home), which is a separate entry from Hyper-V in the settings. Hyper-V [seems to cause some performance issues](https://superuser.com/questions/507186/poor-gaming-performance-with-hyper-v-installed-in-windows-8) even when only the main OS is running, due to its architecture.

If I install and use WSL2, will I suffer from the same performance drop? The docs aren't clear about this.

Comment: Does Hyper-V cause performance issues in the current version, or did it only cause performance issues 8 years ago?

Comment: First, keep in mind that WSL/WSL2 **is not a replacement for a fully-fleged Linux installation** even if it uses the VM platform.  It will still have limitations on what it can do.  Also, you need to be more specific regarding Hyper-V - it has performance problems when you don't tune it right and give too many resources to the guests, but that's any Type 2 hypervisor (like Hyper-V, VirtualBox, VMware Workstation, etc.)

Comment: Be careful here.. WSL1 has better (faster) interoperability between windows and linux.  For instance, operating on NTFS files from the linux instance and piping data between the two systems is superior with WSL1 (IMHO).  Almost everything else is better with WSL2.   WSL1 CHUGGED when doing file intensive operations (like using linux `git status`).  The bad thing about the hyper-v option is that it disables other virtual environments like VirtualBox.  Microsoft *could* fix this as it isn't a limitation of virtualization technology but they choose not to.  My guess is that it is on purpose.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas VirtualBox can already run under Hyper-V https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/hyperv-support.html

Comment: Host OS performance when Hyper-V is installed is mostly based on the host's driver ability to deal with the Hypervisor layer's parent partition.  If the drivers are well written, you should see little performance impact.  Regardless, you will see a slight performance decrease since the host OS is now in a what is essentially a special VM with direct access to the hardware.

Comment: VirtualBox and VMware Workstation, which are type 2 hypervisors that run on top of the OS do work with Hyper-V now.  You need to have a recent version of Windows as well as the correct version of VirtualBox or Workstation.